# Why my `IBAction` linked to another Project’s main.storyboard's view

Tags: ios, interface-builder

I copied a file named `xxcontroller.m` from another project.
And than I found `-(IBAction)XXX` is linked to the previous project!
How to delete this relation?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking.  What's linked and from where to where?  How do you know something is linked?  Have you tried cleaning & rebuilding?

Comment: I copied  1.m from A.xcodepro to B.xcodepro. There is a function -(IBAction)XXX in 1.m. and it linked to a button in A.xcodepro. Now, I found the -(IBAction)XXX in B.xcodepro is linked to A.xcodepro's button.!  I'am sorry I didn't make

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just delete that connection by renaming the `-(IBAction)XXX` to `-(IBAction)YYY` & replace the name to `YYY` from where you are calling it in `selector`. And hope it will solve your issue.

Happy Coding

Comment: This answer is even more confusing than the question.

Comment: @nhgrif wongkoo, told that his IBAction method is linked, this can be known by the filled bubble indicating a connection on the left side of the action method, by that I got to get an idea of what he would be talking about. After that, he asked to break that connection, so I suggested him to break that connection by renaming the method. Thats it. What's confusing you now?